# SeekArc is always circle

Tags: android

I use library: https://github.com/Ross-Gibson/SeekArc.
and I have strange situation. 
This is code in xml:

```
<com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
     android: id = "@+id/seekArcRestPauseTime"
     android: layout_width = "match_parent"
     android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android: paddingLeft = "@dimen/fit_2BU"
     android: paddingTop = "@dimen/fit_3BU"
     seekarc: rotation = "180"
     seekarc: startAngle = "50"
     seekarc: sweepAngle = "260"
     seekarc: touchInside = "true"
     seekarc: arcWidth = "@dimen/fit_BU"
     seekarc: progressWidth = "@dimen/fit_BU"
     seekarc: enabled = "false"
     seekarc: roundEdges = "true"
     seekarc: arcColor = "@color/blue_heart"
     seekarc: progressColor = "@color/yellow_heart" / >
```

as you can see I add startAngle and sweepAngle. On my samsung s3 with android 4.3 seekarc looks great, but on samsung s6 with android 5.1.1 my seekarc is always shown as circle, without start angle. When I set progress on 1, seek arc looks properly, but when I set 0 angles disapear and again see whole circe. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

I believe I got the solution after the long time thinking,

In your SeekArc file there is method called

```
private void updateProgress(int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if (progress == INVALID_PROGRESS_VALUE) {
        return;
    }
    //This is the key area to block the looping [Starts]
    if (mProgress == mMax && progress != (mProgress - 1)) {
        return;
    }
    if (mProgress == mMin && progress != (mProgress + 1)) {
        return;
    }
    // This is the key area to block the looping [Ends]
    progress = (progress > mMax) ? mMax : progress;
    progress = (progress < 0) ? 0 : progress;
    mProgress = progress;

    if (mOnSeekArcChangeListener != null) {
        mOnSeekArcChangeListener.onProgressChanged(this, progress,
                fromUser);
    }

    mProgressSweep = (float) progress / mMax * mSweepAngle;

    updateThumbPosition();

    invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this library, he solved this bug in his library
https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress

It will works fine if not please let me know, will give you its edited version of mine......

Hope it works for you.

Comment: The library which you have updated is not having manual swiping.

Comment: Can you please explain me the issue, because its running fine on Nexus 6 with android 7.0 Nougat.....

Comment: I can not able to sweep the arc from one position to another.

Comment: can you send me the code of the case where you got this issue.....i mean the values you provide to your SeekArc....